# How can I use WeakReferences for Listeners (Observer Pattern) to avoid memory leaks?

Tags: java, memory-management, listener, observer-pattern, weak-references

I have a 10-15 year code pool which leaks memory by keeping strong references to objects from the observers. These objects are not garbage collected.

I am looking for a solution to prevent this by using WeakReferences.

Comment: You need to formulate this as a question / answer.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't really the spot to write a blog.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: @sp00m Yes, you can answer your own questions. There's no question here, though.

Comment: @aioobe is this better?

Comment: You should post the answer in the answer text box. Not in the question text box.

Comment: @MortenGrum The proper way would be to ask the question (first line of your post) in the question section, and place the answer (the rest of the post) in the answer section below. (Not sure why you got downvoted: although the question could be closed in its current form, it is useful and shows a good research effort)

Comment: Ok - think I got it. Will modify. Thanks @aioobe

Comment: @MortenGrum, your question is not very clear. This depends on what memory problems you have. Memory leaks? Memory footprint? GC-overhead? Also, the grammatical errors doesn't really help.

Answer (score 1):

I've done a bit to check it out myself (see below). Do you agree with my conclusions?

**Intro:**

Here are 7 different trials demonstrating the use and miss-use of strong and weak references in the context of the observer model (listener model). I know that there are already lots of posts on pros & cons of weak references out there but even after grinding my way through tons of these I still felt I needed to feel-it-with-code. My need-to-know was sparked by encountering heap leaks when scaling a 10-15 year code pool with lost of listeners (non-gui listeners). Thought the results and code might be useful for others wanting to get clear on this topic.

Comments/ammendments/alternatives are welcome!

---

**Conclusion:**

Always use one of two strategies:

- Strong references to listeners and then make sure every single one of them is removed before the listeners "owner" (or owners owners ...) is dropped and becomes inaccessible (case C below). This means stringently implementing (and using!) "free()" or "destroy()" methods on practically all your classes.
- Weak references to listeners that are fields on their owner class (i.e. listeners should not be local method variables) (case E below).

If you are creating a **library** for others to use, **weak reference to listeners is probably not an option** because neither at compile time nor runtime does java have any way of checking that a listener registering on a subject has a strong link in the other end. Note that contrary to much discussion around, the issue has nothing to do with whether or not the listener is an anonymous class. It is purely an issue of how the listener is hooked up in "the other end" (the end that is not on the subject side but on the observer side).

---

**Here is my console output:**

At the end of the day - no surprises, but simply a confirmation of what one would in fact expect. If a listener has a strong references in either end of the observer model then it won't be garbage collected. If it has only weak references then your objects might be garbage collected before you want it (see for example case G where notifiedCount is 0).

```
    A. WITHOUT connecting listeners
       At start, memory used = 281 KB
       After instantiation 100 observers with a double[1000000] each, memory used = 800288 KB
       After setting list of observes to null, memory used = 282 KB

    B. STRONG references to FIELD listeners
       At start, memory used = 286 KB
       After instantiation 100 observers with a double[1000000] each, memory used = 800291 KB
       After making change on subject (notifiedCount=100), memory used = 800292 KB
       After setting list of observes to null, memory used = 800292 KB

    C. STRONG references to FIELD listeners with REMOVE
       At start, memory used = 286 KB
       After instantiation 100 observers with a double[1000000] each, memory used = 800292 KB
       After making change on subject (notifiedCount=100), memory used = 800293 KB
       After removing listeners, memory used = 800292 KB
       After setting list of observes to null, memory used = 286 KB

    D. STRONG references to LOCAL listeners
       At start, memory used = 286 KB
       After instantiation 100 observers with a double[1000000] each, memory used = 800295 KB
       After making change on subject (notifiedCount=100), memory used = 800295 KB
       After setting list of observes to null, memory used = 800294 KB

    E. WEAKLY references to FIELD listeners
       At start, memory used = 287 KB
       After instantiation 100 observers with a double[1000000] each, memory used = 800297 KB
       After making change on subject (notifiedCount=100), memory used = 800297 KB
       After setting list of observes to null, memory used = 291 KB

    F. WEAKLY references to FIELD listeners with REMOVE
       At start, memory used = 287 KB
       After instantiation 100 observers with a double[1000000] each, memory used = 800297 KB
       After making change on subject (notifiedCount=100), memory used = 800297 KB
       After removing listeners, memory used = 800294 KB
       After setting list of observes to null, memory used = 288 KB

    G. WEAKLY references to LOCAL listeners
       At start, memory used = 287 KB
       After instantiation 100 observers with a double[1000000] each, memory used = 800297 KB
       After making change on subject (notifiedCount=0), memory used = 800297 KB
       After setting list of observes to null, memory used = 291 KB
```

---

**What I did:**

**STEP 1:** I created two different listener support classes:

- one with classic strong references to its listeners:

```
public class ListenerSupportWithStrongReferences implements ListenerSupport {
    List<PropertyChangeListener> strongListeners = new ArrayList<PropertyChangeListener>

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(
            PropertyChangeListener propertyChangeListener) {
        strongListeners.add(propertyChangeListener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(
            PropertyChangeListener propertyChangeListener) {
        strongListeners.remove(propertyChangeListener);
    }

    public void firePropertyChangeEvent(PropertyChangeEvent propertyChangeEvent) {
        for(PropertyChangeListener strongListener : strongListeners){
            strongListener.propertyChange(propertyChangeEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

- and another with weak references to its listeners:

```
public class ListenerSupportWithWeakReferences implements ListenerSupport {

    List<WeakReference<PropertyChangeListener>> weakListeners = 
        new ArrayList<WeakReference<PropertyChangeListener>>();

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(
            PropertyChangeListener propertyChangeListener) {
        weakListeners.add(new WeakReference<PropertyChangeListener>(propertyChangeListener));
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(
            PropertyChangeListener propertyChangeListener) {
        for(WeakReference<PropertyChangeListener> weakReference : weakListeners){
            if(weakReference.get()==propertyChangeListener){
                weakListeners.remove(weakReference);
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    public void firePropertyChangeEvent(PropertyChangeEvent propertyChangeEvent) {
        for(WeakReference<PropertyChangeListener> weakReference : weakListeners){
            PropertyChangeListener propertyChangeListener = weakReference.get();
            if(propertyChangeListener!=null)
                propertyChangeListener.propertyChange(propertyChangeEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

both support classes implement the interface:

```
public interface ListenerSupport extends SubjectInterface {

    public void firePropertyChangeEvent(PropertyChangeEvent propertyChangeEvent);
}
```

which in turn extends the interface:

```
public interface SubjectInterface {

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener propertyChangeListener);
    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener propertyChangeListener);
}
```

**STEP 2:** I created a concrete subject class allowing me to control the type of listerner support through the constructor and on which I could change a value that would notify listeners using whatever listener support had been instantiated.

```
public class ConcreteSubject implements SubjectInterface {

    public static final String STRONG_LISTENERS = "STRONG_LISTENERS";
    public static final String WEAK_LISTENERS = "WEAK_LISTENERS";

    private final ListenerSupport listenerSupport;
    private int myValue;

    public ConcreteSubject(String typeOfListeners) {
        if(typeOfListeners.equals(STRONG_LISTENERS)){
            listenerSupport = new ListenerSupportWithStrongReferences();
        } else if(typeOfListeners.equals(WEAK_LISTENERS)){
            listenerSupport = new ListenerSupportWithWeakReferences();
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unknown type of listeners:"+typeOfListeners);
        }
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(
            PropertyChangeListener propertyChangeListener) {
        listenerSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(propertyChangeListener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(
            PropertyChangeListener propertyChangeListener) {
        listenerSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(propertyChangeListener);
    }

    private void fireMyValueHasChange(int oldValue, int newValue){
        PropertyChangeEvent propertyChangeEvent = 
            new PropertyChangeEvent(this, "SomeEvent", new Integer(oldValue), new Integer(newValue));
        listenerSupport.firePropertyChangeEvent(propertyChangeEvent);
    }

    public int getMyValue() {
        return myValue;
    }

    public void setMyValue(int myValue) {
        int oldValue = this.myValue;
        this.myValue = myValue;
        fireMyValueHasChange(oldValue, this.myValue);
    }
}
```

**STEP 3:** I created an observing class with a large double array so as to take up a noticable amount of memory. I also gave the observing class the ability to serve two different listeners:
 - a field listener created on instantiation of the observer itself (so the observer had a strong reference to its listener) and
 - a listener that created within the method returning it (so the observer had no reference to its listener).
I also created a counter to keep track of notifications.

```
public class ObservingObject {

    public final static int DOUBLE_ARRAY_SIZE = 1000000;
    private double[] myDoubles = new double[DOUBLE_ARRAY_SIZE];
    private int notifiedCount = 0;

    private PropertyChangeListener fieldListener = new PropertyChangeListener() {
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent arg0) {
            notifiedCount++;
        }
    };

    public PropertyChangeListener getFieldPropertyChangeListener() {
        return fieldListener;
    }

    public PropertyChangeListener getLocalMethodPropertyChangeListener() {
        PropertyChangeListener localListenerInstance = new PropertyChangeListener() {
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent arg0) {
                notifiedCount++;
            }
        };
        return localListenerInstance;
    }

    public int getNotifiedCount() {
        return notifiedCount;
    }
}
```

**STEP 4:** Finally, I created my main class to try out 7 different "configurations" of:

- strong/weak references to listeners,
- field/method-local listeners,
- with/without rempoving the listeners.

  The output of this main trials class is listed above. Note that I call the garbage collector before calculating memory used to ensure that what I'm seeing is the memory actually hanging or used.

```
public class WeakReferenceListenerTrials {

    private static final String LOCAL_LISTENER = "local method listener";
    private static final String FIELD_LISTENER = "field listener";
    List<ObservingObject> observers;

    private void runTials() {
        runTrial("A. WITHOUT connecting listeners", null, null, false);
        runTrial("B. STRONG references to FIELD listeners", 
                new ConcreteSubject(ConcreteSubject.STRONG_LISTENERS), FIELD_LISTENER, false);
        runTrial("C. STRONG references to FIELD listeners with REMOVE", 
                new ConcreteSubject(ConcreteSubject.STRONG_LISTENERS), FIELD_LISTENER, true);
        runTrial("D. STRONG references to LOCAL listeners", 
                new ConcreteSubject(ConcreteSubject.STRONG_LISTENERS), LOCAL_LISTENER, false);
        runTrial("E. WEAKLY references to FIELD listeners", 
                new ConcreteSubject(ConcreteSubject.WEAK_LISTENERS), FIELD_LISTENER, false);
        runTrial("F. WEAKLY references to FIELD listeners with REMOVE", 
                new ConcreteSubject(ConcreteSubject.WEAK_LISTENERS), FIELD_LISTENER, true);
        runTrial("G. WEAKLY references to LOCAL listeners", 
                new ConcreteSubject(ConcreteSubject.WEAK_LISTENERS), LOCAL_LISTENER, false);
    }

    private void runTrial(String titleText, 
            ConcreteSubject subject, String localOrFieldListeners, boolean removeListeners) {
        System.out.println("\n"+titleText);
        printMem("   At start");

        instantiateObserversAndConnectListenersToSubject(subject, localOrFieldListeners);
        printMem("   After instantiation 100 observers with a double["+ObservingObject.DOUBLE_ARRAY_SIZE+"] each");

        if(subject!=null){
            subject.setMyValue(1);
            int notifiedCount = 0;
            for(ObservingObject observingObject : observers){
                notifiedCount = notifiedCount + observingObject.getNotifiedCount();
            }
            printMem("   After making change on subject (notifiedCount="+notifiedCount+")");
        }

        if(removeListeners){
            removeListeners(subject, localOrFieldListeners);
            printMem("   After removing listeners");
        }

        observers = null;
        printMem("   After setting list of observes to null");
    }

    private void removeListeners(ConcreteSubject subject,
            String localOrFieldListeners) {
        if(localOrFieldListeners.equals(FIELD_LISTENER) && subject!=null){
            for(ObservingObject observingObject :observers){
                subject.removePropertyChangeListener(observingObject.getFieldPropertyChangeListener());
            }
        }
    }

    private void instantiateObserversAndConnectListenersToSubject(
            ConcreteSubject subject, String localOrFieldListeners) {
        observers = new ArrayList<ObservingObject>();
        int observerCount = 100;
        for(int i = 0 ; i lt observerCount ; i++){
            ObservingObject observingObject = new ObservingObject();
            observers.add(observingObject);
            if(subject!=null){
                if(localOrFieldListeners.equals(FIELD_LISTENER)){
                    subject.addPropertyChangeListener(observingObject.getFieldPropertyChangeListener());
                } else if(localOrFieldListeners.equals(LOCAL_LISTENER)){
                    subject.addPropertyChangeListener(observingObject.getLocalMethodPropertyChangeListener());
                } else {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Unknow listener type");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void printMem(String string) {
        System.out.println(string+", memory used = "+getUsedMemoryInKB()+" KB");
    }

    private static int getUsedMemoryInKB() {
        // Start by garbage collect
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        runtime.gc();

        // Calculate 'used memory' as difference between total and free
        long totalMemory = runtime.totalMemory();
        long freeMemory = runtime.freeMemory();
        long usedMemory = totalMemory - freeMemory;
        int usedMemoryInKB = (int)(usedMemory/1000);
        return usedMemoryInKB;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new WeakReferenceListenerTrials().runTials();
    }
}
```

That's it. Hope its useful to others. It was to me.